# Log4net is not creating the log file after installation windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, log4net

I have a windows service project with log4net. If I install the service via installutil.exe then everything works fine. I adding windows setup project - service starting and work, but not creating log files.

My conf

```
<configSections>
    <section name="ConnectionInfo" type="Astra.Common.Configuration.ConnectionInfoConfiguration, Astra.Common" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=2.0.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" />
  </configSections>
```

...

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="Logs\service.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p %m%n" />
      </layout>

    </appender>

    <logger name="LOGGER">
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Class

```
public static class Logger
    {
        private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("LOGGER");


        public static ILog Log
        {
            get { return log; }
        }

        public static void InitLogger()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        static Logger()
        {
            InitLogger();
        }
    }


[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

Service as NetworkService

Comment: Make sure the service account can write to that folder. If so, [enable log4net debugging](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/) and check the output.

Comment: Oh, also, check what path the service is trying to create the files in - IIRC windows services start with `system32` as the current directory.

Comment: @stuartd Thank ! Account in my service dont have permissions to write in directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file appender, make sure you are writing to a location where the user is allowed to create and update the files. If not the logging will fail. You can check this when you have internal debugging enabled.